# Spotify / Rdio Bottom Toolbar View Controller Transition

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

Could anybody point me in the right direction for implementing the type of functionality that Spotify and Rdio use for their "Now Playing" bottom toolbar?  There is an ability to touch and drag a view controller over the top of another view controller.  The entire transition is interactive.  Any help would be appreciated!  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely they're just using UIPanGestureRecognizers and maybe UITapGestureRecognizer if you can tap the bottom bar to make it slide up.

Maybe make some container controller that holds your main nav stack, with the mini player at the bottom, and the full player hidden off screen. Then using the gesture recognizer, you can drag it up to reveal the full player.